# Generate barcode with Free 3 of 9 font

Tags: c#, barcode

```
public Bitmap CreateBarcode(string data)
{
    data = "55536"; 
    string barcodeData = "*" + data + "*";
    Bitmap barcode = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Font threeOfNine = new Font("Free 3 of 9 Extended", 31, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);

    Font arial = new Font("Arial", 13,
              System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
              System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(barcode);
    SizeF dataSize = graphics.MeasureString(barcodeData, threeOfNine);
    dataSize.Height = 70;

    barcode = new Bitmap(barcode, dataSize.ToSize());
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(barcode);

    graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;

    graphics.DrawString(barcodeData, threeOfNine, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);

    graphics.DrawString(data, arial, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 50, 40);

    graphics.Flush();

    threeOfNine.Dispose();
    graphics.Dispose();

    return barcode;
}
```

I generate barcode with the above code, but my scanner can not read the barcode generated (for 55536).
BUT if I switch the data value to "1111" or "2222", then the barcode be read very well.
so I think it is not a scanner problem, anybody know, what's the wrong with that code?
please advice.

Comment: Where did you get this font from?

Comment: And a follow up question, can it read 11111? You're not really comparing apples to apples because the real barcode is five digits but the test ones are four.

Comment: Unrelated, but you assign a new Bitmap(1, 1) to barcode and then later set it to a different Bitmap instance. The first bitmap leaks because you never dispose of it. You should use the using() statement with disposable objects as it will make the scope of disposable objects more obvious and make dealing with the disposal less problematic. Also the Arial font is leaking.

Comment: I downloaded font from http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud Yes, I can read 11111, but not for 55555

Comment: @Expertwannabe, I found when trying to get free bar code fonts to work that they had one of two limitations a) it would only properly output a string of a certain length or b) it would only go up to a maximum letter/number - this is almost certainly what you're facing.

Comment: It would help if you include the images for the unreadable "55536" and readable "11111" barcode.

Comment: Coming in quite late to this but just ran across this post. Your scanner may require '*' prepended and appended like this: *5555*. My Motorola hand-held doesn't generate an error without the asterisks, just nothing is recorded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using only numbers, you could try the 3 of 9 basic font (without the extended).  Print the same barcode from Write and compare them to see if your solution is building the complete barcode or if it is getting truncated.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you're using the supported characters surrounded by the "*" stop and start characters, chances are the problem is either the size of the barcode or the resolution of the printing. 
2.Make sure that the size of each character is the same font size. Mixed sizes will not work.
3.When experimenting with changing the color of the bars, remember that darker colors are better. Pastels are not so good. Red is a no-no.
Here's a reference for you: [asp.net barcode generator using 3 of 9 font](http://www.onbarcode.com/csharp/code-39-generator.html).

Answer (score -2):

try to prefix and suffix :

why are you passing the data within the

```
public Bitmap CreateBarcode(string data)
{
    data="55536"; //dont pass the data from here pass it from outside method for eg. call it   from the        button click or whatever control you are using.
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this answer is anyway related to the question asked.